# How do I count n-gram occurrences in many lists

Tags: python, n-gram

Do anyone know if it is possible to count from a vocabulary of n grams, how many times these each occur in several different lists of tokens? The vocabulary is made with n grams from the lists, where each unique n gram is listed once. If I have:

lists

```
['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', 'are', 'you', 'okay'] //1

['hello', 'I', 'am', 'doing', 'okay', 'are', 'you', 'okay'] //2

<type = list>
```

N-gram Vocabulary

```
('hello','I')
('I', 'am')
('am', 'doing')
('doing', 'okay')
('okay','are')
('hello', 'how')
('how', 'are')
('are','you')
('you', 'doing')
('doing', 'today')
('today', 'are')
('you', 'okay')
<type = tupels>
```

Then I want the output to be something like:

list 1 :

```
('hello', 'how')1
('how', 'are')1
('are','you')2
('you', 'doing')1
('doing', 'today')1
('today', 'are')1
('you', 'okay')1
```

list 2 :

```
('hello','I')1
('I', 'am')1
('am', 'doing')1
('doing', 'okay')1
('okay','are')1
('are','you')1
('you', 'okay')1
```

I have the following code:

```
test_tokenized = [word_tokenize(i) for i in test_lower]

for test_toke in test_tokenized:

    filtered_words = [word for word in test_toke if word not in stopwords.words('english')]

    bigram = bigrams(filtered_words)

    fdist = nltk.FeatDict(bigram)

    for k,v in fdist.items():
        #print (k,v)
        occur = (k,v)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension to generate the ngrams and `collections.Counter` to count duplicates:

```
from collections import Counter
l = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', 'are', 'you', 'okay']
ngrams = [(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1)]
print Counter(ngrams)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a for loop with range:

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'doing', 'today', 'are', 'you', 'okay']
list2 = ['hello', 'I', 'am', 'doing', 'okay', 'are', 'you', 'okay'] 

def ngram(li):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(li)-1):
        result.append((li[i], li[i+1]))
    return Counter(result)

print(ngram(list1))
print(ngram(list2))
```